# Bootstrap Template Migration to ASP.NET 4.5 Forms- Full Width Rendering Issue

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

http://www.petcenters.com/htmlpage1.html is a re-build of a Bootstrap Template that I purchased.  I copied that template into htmlpage1.html which was added to the project.  This runs fine.

I have attempted to migrate this htmlpage1.html into an ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms project by separating that out into the MasterPage and Default.aspx.

http://www.petcenters.com

I'm having an issue with the LayerSlider and Footer not rendering full-width as shown in the http://www.petcenters.com/htmlpage1.html

Here is the Master Page:

```
<body class="header-fixed">
<form runat="server">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header header-sticky">
            <div class="container">
            .....
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <div class="footer-v1">
            .....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  <!--/wrapper-->
</form>
</body>
```

Here is the Default.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div id="layerslider" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; margin: 0px auto;">
    .....
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I can't tell if this wrapper class is causing the problem.  Still, I haven't been able to successfully de-bug this to determine why the LayerSlider and Footer are not full-width.  Also the Header appears wider.

http://www.petcenters.com/htmlpage1.html    Bootstrap HTML Template runs fine

http://www.petcenters.com   Bootstrap HTML Template into MasterPage and Default.aspx.

An insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried adding the bootstrap class: "container-fluid" to the footer?

Also, what is the CSS for the "wrapper" class.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky I didn't make any changes to the CSS as this works fine in the HTML Page.  "container-fluid" is already part of the header-default.css

Comment: I've got your answer.

Comment: the problem is the body-content class.  Try removing it and see what happens.

Comment: <div class="container body-content">  to  <div class="container">  had no effect.

Comment: <div class="container body-content">  Actually, "container" that is part of the Master Page is not part of the boostrap tempate.

Comment: I didn't notice that difference when I viewed the source.  The bootstrap container will pad the left and right margins, container-fluid wont.  That may be the issue right there.  Something is padding your margins.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky I dont think it's the boostrap container causing padding, because this works in HTMLPage1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `<div class="container body-content">` to `<div class="container-fluid body-content">` seems to fix the problem.

The bootstrap class `container` is setting a static `width` at certain break points.

Comment: Do you notice the Header having an expanded width?  Do you have any clue about that?

Comment: @Paul Yes the header nav is wrapped in a `container` class too and is also getting a static width so it is also not taking up the full width

Comment: when you say its not taking up the full width, I'm not clear on that, because it appears to be taking up more than the width of the bootstrap template.

Comment: It does appear to be taller on http://www.petcenters.com/, but that is because the `body` has 50px of padding

Comment: That fact it's an .aspx page should not matter. The template does not have the `layerSlider` wrapped in `<div class="content body-content">`, that seems to be the difference

Comment: I apologize for the dumb question.  I didn't change any of the CSS for the body.  This problem existed prior to changing to "container-fluid"

Comment: The grey line in the header comes from the `header` class which is wrapping the `container` div in the header

Comment: Can you put your `layerSlider` outside and before `<div class="container body-content">`?

Comment: Anything inside the bootstrap class `container` will never take the full width unless you override the style

Comment: layerSlider is part of the Default.aspx not within the MasterPage.  I could illustrate this in the description.  The MasterPage has <div class="container-flue body-content">  The Default has <div id="layerslider" >

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73459/discussion-between-zgood-and-paul).

Comment: when I mean "width" of the Header I'm referring to the "height" issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the 2nd part of the solution:

The HTML Page Template didn't have:

```
<div class="container body-content">
```

Bootstrap is part of the ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms Template.
The MasterPage does have:

```
<div class="container body-content">
```

Modified MasterPage div container to:

```
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
```

Made a helper class .no-padding { padding: 0 !important; } and added that class to container-fluid

```
.container-fluid .no-padding { padding: 0 !important; }
```

Mofified container-fluid div to this:

```
<div class="container-fluid body-content no-padding">
```